# How to properly separate render thread from logic thread?

Tags: architecture, multithreading, synchronization, glfw

I am not asking about parallelization of physics and so on stuff with `parallel_for()` like stuff.

I've managed to have separate rendering thread from logic thread, in glfw3 application:

```
void render_thread() {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose(win) ) {
        sleep(10); // emulate heavy rendering, to be sure that main loop stops event processing during this sleep
        glfwSetWindowTitle(win, "some title"); // posts message? to window queue to update title
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(nullptr);
}
```

And init/event/input handling loop is as follows:

```
void main_thread() {
    set_thread_priority(highest); // to be sure this is first priority in OS sheduler, compared to render thread
    win = glfwCreateWindow(...);
    std::thread rt(&render_thread);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(_glWindow))
        glfwWaitEvents(); // could put thread to sleep
    rt.join();
}
```

Here is the problem, when i click to close window:

- `rt.join()` never returns, because it waits for `render_thread()` to return
- `render_thread()` could not return from `glfwSetWindowTitle()` call, seems no message processing goes on, or something other that i dont know.

Maybe my whole approach is wrong, but how should i solve that in a sane way?